# scrapy deploy -L returns nothing

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, scrapyd

I'm trying to deploy my scrapy project, but I'm stuck

I definately do have working project and several spiders:

```
deploy@susychoosy:~/susy_scraper$ scrapy
Scrapy 0.17.0 - project: clothes_spider
```

and when I do scrapy list it shows list of all spiders.

I modified my scrapy.cfg file so it looks like that:

```
[settings]
default = clothes_spider.settings
[deploy:scrapyd]
url = http://localhost:6800/
project = clothes_spider
```

Then I do:

```
deploy@susychoosy:~/susy_scraper$ scrapy deploy -l
scrapyd              http://localhost:6800/
```

so everything seems to be fine, however in next step i dont see any projects available:

```
deploy@susychoosy:~/susy_scraper$ scrapy deploy -L scrapyd

deploy@susychoosy:~/susy_scraper$
```

I tried typing directly:

```
deploy@susychoosy:~/susy_scraper$ scrapy deploy -L scrapyd -p clothes_spider

deploy@susychoosy:~/susy_scraper$
```

But it didn't help.

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to deploy a project to a target first:

```
$ scrapy deploy scrapyd -p clothes_spider
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the output in the terminal of "scrapy server" when you type "scrapy deploy -L scrapyd"?
It should be like this, with the "listprojects.json":

```
2013-03-13 10:43:33+0800 [HTTPChannel,0,127.0.0.1] 127.0.0.1 - - [13/Mar/2013:02:43:33 +0000] "GET /listprojects.json HTTP/1.1" 200 42 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
```